# Por qual razão PHP permite criar nomes de identificadores com caracteres especiais?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem

Normalmente nas linguagens de programação e bancos de dados, nomes de identificadores (variáveis, funções, classes, métodos, tabelas, campos etc) devem começar obrigatoriamente com uma letra ou *underline*, números podem vir na sequência e para evitar problemas caracteres acentuados e especiais devem ser evitados.

No PHP as variáveis devem começar com um cifrão `$` porém é possível criar identificadores com nomes estranhos como os abaixo:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

function executarAção($ação){
    echo $ação .' <br>';
}

function 웃(){
    echo 'boneco de palito da uml é você mesmo? <br>';
}

function variavelEstranha(){
    ${0} = 'Olá mundo estranho :D';
    echo ${0};  
}

executarAção('kboom');
웃();
variavelEstranha();
```

**Pergunta:**

Por qual razão o PHP permite criar variáveis e funções com caracteres especiais?

[**Exemplo**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xm0r-h8bp)

<sub>Obs: no meu teste, salvei o arquivo como utf-8.</sub>

Comment: Por qual razão não permitiria?

Comment: Provavelmente a razão é falta de razão (ou planejamento) para não permitir.

Comment: Que parada bizarra, não sabia que dava pra fazer isso, kkk +1 pelos exemplos

Comment: @utluiz Pois é, se não tem razão para proibir, não precisa de uma razão para não proibir.

Comment: Já vi vários arquivos PHP começando com `<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`... Eu sabia porquê, mas esqueci...

Comment: E também não sei por que downvotar sem deixar uma dica do problema com esta questão.

Comment: Mostra toda falta de coerência do PHP... Reconhece a função `executarAção`, mas a própria função nativa para contar o tamanho de uma string não reconhece acentos.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Talvez você esteja enganado. Poste uma pergunta sobre isso para a galera poder analisar. Em algumas codificações o tamanho de cada caracter, em bytes, varia.

Comment: @Caffé, não é uma pergunta, é uma demonstração de com o PHP pode causa essas 'confusões'.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Pelo menos nesse aspecto, pra mim não causa não. É só não confundir `strlen()` com `mb_strlen()`.

Comment: @Caffé, cada um é livre para votar como lhe der na telha sem obrigação de explicar porquê (seria legal, mas não é obrigado)... Acho que o +6 vs -1 fala por si só.

Comment: Para nomes de funções não sabia que permitia.. Interessante.. Eu sei que pode usar também em índices de arrays array('漢字'=>null)...   Fora do mundo PHP, se PHP é "confuso ou bizarro" por permitir isso, o Oracle também é pois nomes de base de dados, tabelas e colunas aceitam caracteres especiais também.

Comment: @DanielOmine MS SQL Server também não tem essa restrição. Na verdade não sei de nenhuma linguagem que não permita usar "caracteres especiais".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Porque programadores de outros lugares do mundo, como da Arábia Saudita, por exemplo, provavelmente gostariam de poder criar uma função assim:

```
نفعلشيئا()
```

Não há nenhum motivo para o compilador proibir o uso de "caracteres especiais" no código fonte.

Você pode convencionar o não uso no seu projeto, por algum motivo específico, e pode ainda configurar um analisador de código fonte para quebrar o build caso encontre caracteres proibidos por convenção. Mas o compilador não conhece alguns aspectos da cultura do seu time ou não está preocupado.

**Update:** desculpe o uso da palavra "compilador" :-) Algumas linguagens são apenas interpretadas. Mas a resposta é a mesma.

A propósito, o seu exemplo, 웃, parece ser um carcter válido na Coreia ("sorridente", segundo o Google Translate).

**Update 2 - uma breve reflexão:** Por que não usamos caracteres especiais nos nossos sistemas?

### O que torna um caracter especial?

[Nesta documentação](http://windows.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-vista/insert-a-special-character-into-a-document-ascii-codes) de um recurso do Windows, encontrei uma definição interessante:

> Caracteres especiais são caracteres que não são encontrados no
>   teclado.

Ora, no meu teclado eu vejo tudo que eu preciso para escrever *"executarAção"*. Então alguma definição de caracter especial está errada (a nossa aqui nesta pergunta ou a do documentador da Microsoft).

Eu gostei mais desta [outra definição](http://www.ime.usp.br/~glauber/html/acentos.htm):

> São caracteres como pontos, símbolos (@ * ! % ; : . ) ou espaços em
>   branco que não são aceitos pelo sistema de cadastro para preenchimento
>   dos campos nome de usuário e senha.

Aí sim uma boa definição. Ela estabele o domínio para sua definição de caracteres especiais: determinados campos do sistema de cadastro.

Então, concluo que a definição de "caracteres especiais" varia de acordo com o contexto. O que é caracter especial aqui, pode não ser ali.

### Nossa definição de caracter especial:

Nós, programadores de língua portuguesa, consideramos especiais até os caracteres que fazem parte da nossa vida: cedilha e acentuação. Não gostamos deles nos nossos sistemas porque... porque... por que mesmo? Claro, nem precisamos de definição formal, nossa experiência revela que isso só dá problema:

- Cada programador salva o arquivo com uma codificação diferente, então o cedilha que você salvou na sua máquina aparece como um símbolo estranho na minha.
- Cada aplicativo que usa o nosso banco de dados foi compilado ou será interpretado usando uma codificação diferente, então o SELECT que escrevi num aplicativo usando cedilha não encontrará a tabela criada com cedilha a partir de outro aplicativo.
- Cada programador tem uma "noção" diferente de quais palavras são acentuadas, então a função que eu nomeio com um acento não será facilmente encontrada por outro programador que acredita que a palavra não leve acento.
- E por aí vai...

**Conclusão:** ora, um programador bem-intencionado do PHP deve achar bacana que os de língua portuguesa possam usar sua acentuação, tão comum, no código fonte. Se o interpretador não tem problemas em lidar com estes caracteres, por que limitar seu uso? E, é claro, como já mencionei, há muitos idiomas por aí usando os mais diversos "caracteres especiais".

Os problemas que citei podem ser ignorados por este programador do PHP pois é "fácil" de eliminá-los: basta que todos usem codificação `UTF-8` nos seus editores e demais ferramentas, e basta que todos conheçam bem seu idioma. Nós não apostamos nisso (eu pelo menos não aposto) e seguimos nossa tradição de convencionar o não uso de caracteres especiais.

É claro que antes do advento e massificação de padrões de codificação mais modernos (UTF-8), os problemas quanto ao uso de "caracteres especiais" eram sérios pois os padrões de codificações eram limitados. Mesmo naquela época os compiladores e interpretadores não podiam fazer muito no sentido de limitar o uso de caracteres pois, como já dito, a definição de quais caracteres são especiais vai variar.

Comment: E o `${0}` não deveria gerar um erro ex: `{` não esperada ou, instrução(if/while/class)  esperada antes da `{` ?

Comment: @perdeu Não necessariamente. O PHP já sabe que você está declarando uma variável dado o `$`, então ele só precisa proibir os caracteres com os quais ele não consegue lidar naquele contexto. Há outras linguagens que não proibem o uso por exemplo de palavras chave em um contexto onde o compilador sabe que não cabe o uso da palavra como palavra chave.