# Por que não posso declarar uma variável com um numérico antes do nome?

Tags: javascript, c#, actionscript-3, sintaxe, declaração-de-variável

Estou curioso em saber o porque de não poder criar variáveis com um número antes do nome. Fiz alguns testes em JavaScript, ActionScript e C#.

```
var 4teste:String = "teste"; //ActionScript, erro!
var 4teste = "teste"; //Javascript, erro!
String 4teste = "teste"; //C#, erro!

var teste4:String = "teste"; //ActionScript, ok!
var teste4 = "teste"; //Javascript, ok!
String teste4 = "teste"; //C#, ok!
```

Sei que o PHP, por exemplo, permite caracteres especiais, mas talvez isto seja por causa do identificador inicial, que é um cifrão `$`.

Existe alguma 'regra' nas linguagens que não permite o uso de números no inicio de uma variável?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Existe a regra porque é ambíguo. Se a variável começar com um número o compilador não sabe que é um símbolo (uma variável, por exemplo). Ele vai achar que é um literal numérico.

Perceba que até aqui no site quando você usa o número iniciando o nome, a colorização acha que é um literal (é bem verdade que nestes casos específicos dá para saber que não é um literal, mas depois teria problema em identificar).

Isto é especialmente complicado quando os literais podem ter letras no final para diferenciar o tipo. Se isto não existisse na linguagem, até daria para o compilador se safar e descobrir o que realmente é. É verdade que ainda dá mesmo isto existindo mas só em certos casos. É melhor nem tentar fazer isto. O ganho seria ínfimo e trataria outras confusões.

Nomes só com números não é possível em nenhuma circunstância, não teria como diferenciar. OK, daria para fazer uma gambi, quando está declarando (se a sintaxe deixa claro que é uma declaração poderia aceitar como sendo um identificador e não um número, aí toda vez que encontrá-lo no código considerará que é o identificador e não pode naquele código ter aquele número literal sendo usado. Mas pra que essa maluquice toda?

O PHP pode ser mais permissivo com alguns símbolos já que a linguagem exige um caractere específico para indicar que aquilo é uma variável.

Algumas linguagens poderiam fazer isto com um caractere opcional de *escape* nestes caso, como é possível usar o `@` no C#, por exemplo. Mas novamente, o ganho não compensa o esforço, dá para viver sem variáveis que começam com números. Note no entanto que o C# permite o uso do `@` apenas para escapar palavras-chave mas não nomes começados com números.

Se você precisar de um nome assim porque vem de um banco de dados que aceita este tipo de nome, é possível, em C# usar um atributo para nomear melhor, não a variável, mas pelo menos dar uma informação de relação com a coluna no BD.

```
var 2d = 1;
WriteLine(2d); //está imprimindo "1" (o valor de 2d), ou imprimindo "2.0" que é um double)
var 3 = 1;
WriteLine(3); //está imprimindo "1" (o valor de 3), ou imprimindo "3" que é um int)
```

Não tem como saber, é ambíguo.

No seu exemplo `4teste` em tese pode não ser ambíguo, mas pra que fazer esta exceção? O ganho não compensa. E se tivesse isto, poderia limitar a expansão da linguagem.

Vamos dizer que um dia a linguagem precise fazer um literal que é determinado pelo sufixo `teste`. Pronto, `4teste` já ficaria ambíguo. Claro que você pode achar que `teste` é um péssimo sufixo, mas um compilador não pode fazer juízo de valor. E a linguagem poderia criar um mecanismo que o programador cria seus próprios sufixos e ele poderia ser `teste` ou outra coisa. Se existisse uma variável com um número e este mesmo nome, complicaria. Exemplo:

```
var 5dias = 1;
//um dia uma pessoa cria o sufixo dias, aí seria permitido:
var x = 5dias; //antes saberia que está guardando 1 em x, agora pode estar guardando 5 dias
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/VariableName.cs).

Comment: Ótima explicação. É muito confuso, o interpretador trata as letras após o caractere numérico como o que exatamente? Ou, em toda circunstância, quando há um caractere numérico inicial, ele trataria como um tipo "Number", "int", "Double", etc, é isso?

Comment: Aí depende da linguagem, C# trataria só números como `int`, se tiver um sufixo `d` seria `double`, se o sufixo for `L` seria `long`, `m` seria `decimal`, e assim vai. Se for uma letra ou palavra não aceito pela linguagem, daria erro. JS trataria como `Number`.

Comment: +1 pelo exemplo do double.

Answer (score 6):

Uma variável não deve iniciar com um número porque dessa forma o compilador/interpretador não sabera diferenciar se é um valor ex: 300 ou se é uma variável, além da confusão para ler o código.

```
var 300 = 10;

if(300 > 500){ ???
}
```

Alguns banco de dados permitem utilizar caracteres especiais ou números no inicio dos nomes porque eles são escapados, no mysql usa-se a crase para isso.

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`300` (
  `id300` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id300`)  COMMENT '');
```

Relacionado: 
[Caracteres especiais em identificadores PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38461/91)

Comment: Mas, ao utilizar o operador de declaração `var` antes do nome, o compilador/interpretador já não saberia que você está declarando uma variável?

Comment: @biio, e no if como ele vai saber se o 300 é realmente 300 ou se é 10.

Comment: Entendi! Concordo em uma variável apenas com caracteres numéricos, mas isso ocorreria em uma variável chamada "4teste"? O interpretador iria reconhecer essa variável sendo o que exatamente, um tipo numérico também?

Comment: @biio, `4teste` será identificado como uma string não escapada.

Comment: @biio Se as variaveis podessem comecar por numeros, poderia dar origem a nomes muito confusos, como por exemplo `187275675a` (nota o `a` no final). Ou pior, `129826O` (o último caractér é um `o`, e não um zero). Ao tornar obrigatório que a primeira letra seja uma letra, esses problemas deixam de existir - assim, pelo primeiro caractér conseguimos facilmente perceber se se trata do nome duma variável ou dum número literal: `a12345` é uma variável, e `12345` é um número.