# Qual é a utilidade de declarar variáveis através de chavetas?

Tags: php, sintaxe

No PHP, as variáveis geralmente tem um padrão para ser seguido em sua declaração.

De acordo com o manual:

> As variáveis no PHP são representadas por um cifrão ($) seguido pelo
>   nome da variável. Os nomes de variável no PHP fazem distinção entre
>   maiúsculas e minúsculas.
>
> Os nomes de variável seguem as mesmas regras como outros rótulos no
>   PHP. Um nome de variável válido se inicia com uma letra ou sublinhado,
>   seguido de qualquer número de letras, algarismos ou sublinhados.

No entanto, notei que é possível "fugir" dessa regra, na hora de definir o nome de uma variável.

Exemplos:

```
${1} = 1; // valor com número

${'1 variavel'} = 'número iniciando';

${'Nome com espaço'} = 'Wallace';

${'***Testando***'}[0][] = 'Array Louco';
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [1 variavel] => número iniciando
    [Nome com espaço] => Wallace
    [***Testando***] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array Louco
                )

        )

)
```

Além das variáveis poderem ser declaradas assim, também é possível (acho que à partir do PHP 5.4), fazer com que os métodos *"fujam"* um pouco do seu padrão.

```
class Teste
{
    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
           echo "Método numérico [$method]";
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $arguments)
    {
        echo "Método númérico estático [$method]";
    }
}

Teste::{'10'}(); // Método numérico estático [10]

$teste = new Teste;

$teste->{'10'}(); // Método numérico
```

> Afinal de contas, qual é a finalidade de as variáveis poderem ser declaradas entre chavetas ?
>
> ---
>
> Existe alguma caso que isso seja útil?

Comment: Acho que teve uma questão similar sobre declaração de variáveis, inclusive alguns exemplos próximos. Vou ver se acho.

Comment: @PapaCharlie, [Caracteres especiais em identificadores](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38461/91) ?

Comment: @rray, essa mesma. Procurei um tempão e não achei... :) Lembro que foi muito esclarecedora quando li.

Comment: @PapaCharlie, tem esse outra também [Existe algum problema em usar caracteres Unicode para identificadores em código?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16555/91).

Comment: A questão em pauta é o "por que o php aceita isso e se posso usar isso"

Comment: Quando as perguntas são esquisitas e a nível de curiosidades geralmente são feitas pelo @WallaceMaxters rsrsrsr, merece o +1 pela dedicação em buscar "curiosidades"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utiliza-se colchetes na declaração de variáveis quando há necessidade em usar nomenclaturas com caracteres reservados ou caracteres que poderiam causar erro de sintaxe numa declaração normal.

É também utilizado para invocar variáveis na montagem de nomes de métodos de objetos ou simples funções.

Exemplo:

```
/**
Declaração normal
*/
$foo = 'bar';

/**
Suponhamos uma situação onde queremos declarar o nome de uma variável contendo caracter de espaço. Fatalmente provocará erro.
*/
$foo bar = 'teste';
```

Nesse caso, podemos usar as chaves

```
${'foo bar'} = 'teste';
```

Isso é também chamado de **variável variável**: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Numa outra situação, não é permitido declarar variáveis com nomes numéricos

```
$1 = 'val';
$2 = 'val';
$3 = 'val';
```

Porém, isso é possível usando a sintaxe especial com chaves:

```
${1} = 'val';
```

Apesar de ser semelhante a *variável variável*, o método com chaves não consegue acessar uma *variável variável*.

```
$v = 1;
$$v = 'ok';

echo $$v; // escreve 'ok'
echo ${'1'}; // provoca erro
echo ${1}; // provoca erro
```

Porém, o contrário é possível

```
${2} = 'ok';
echo ${2}; // escreve 'ok'

$v = 2;
echo $$v; // escreve 'ok'
```

**Coisas "bizarras" tornam-se "possíveis":**

```
${'\\'} = 'val';
echo ${'\\'};

${'  '} = 'val';
echo ${'  '};

${''} = 'val';
echo ${''};

${null} = 'val';
echo ${null};

${''} = 'val';
echo ${''};

${'Wallace gosta do michel teló.'} = 'val';
echo ${'Wallace gosta do michel teló.'};

/**
Nesse último exemplo, percebemos que o intuito não é permitir "coisas bizarras" para mero entretenimento. 
Podemos escrever códigos dessa forma:
*/
function foo()
{
    return null;
}

${foo()} = 'val';
echo ${foo()};
```

A coisa fica um pouco mais interessante quando experimentamos usar em outros locais.

**Invocando métodos de classes dinamicamente:**

```
class foo
{
    public static function bar()
    {
        return 123;
    }
}

echo foo::{'bar'}();

/**
Outras formas equivalentes:
*/
$m = 'bar';
echo foo::$m();

$o = 'foo';
$m = 'bar';
echo $o::$m();

$o = 'foo';
$m = 'bar';
echo ${'o'}::${'m'}();
```

Note que tais recursos dependem da versão do PHP.

Todavia, o programador não pode viajar na maionese e abusar do recurso.

**Injeções**

Deve-se tomar cuidado também com injeções de código provindas do usuário.

```
/**
O usuário pode tentar injetar códigos maliciosos
*/
$p = $_GET['eu_sou_burro_e_deixo_brecha_de_seguranca'];

${$p} = 'val';
echo ${$p};
```

Comment: -1. Eu não gosto de michel teló. Mentira que dei -1. Dei +1. Mas não gosto de Michel Teló, de verdade!

Comment: Sua resposta foi satisfatória ;)

Answer (score 3):

São chaves.
Parêntesis = (), Colchetes = [] e chaves = {}.

Não é só para declarar, é para fazer referência a variáveis, que inclui declarar.

Este uso que você encontrou eu não conhecia o mais próximo era o nome de variável variável (ver link abaixo). Também pode ter algo a haver com a superglobal `$GLOBALS`, que é um array indexado e portanto aceita strings como chaves para os valores.

De qualquer modo, respondendo às duas perguntas: A finalidade é indicar ao interpretador ou compilador ou o que quiser, exatamente quais caracteres fazem parte do nome da variável. Com as chaves é possível resolver ambiguidades.

Exemplo: No PHP é possível escrever o nome das variáveis diretamente dentro de strings:

```
$inicio = "abc";
echo  "As primeiras seis letras são: $inicio def";
```

Só que tem um espaço não desejado, reescrevendo:

```
echo  "As primeiras seis letras são: $iniciodef";
```

Agora o código vai ser interpretado de maneira incorreta, esperando a variável `$iniciodef` que, a princípio, não existe.

```
echo  "As primeiras seis letras são: ${inicio}def";
```

Assim vai funcionar corretamente.

Outro caso é explicado na documentação do PHP

> Para poder utilizar variáveis variáveis com arrays, você precisa
>   resolver um problema de ambigüidade. Assim, se você escrever $$a[1]
>   então o interpretador pode entender que você quer usar $a[1] como uma
>   variável ou que você quer usar $$a como uma variável e [1] como o
>   índice dessa variável. A sintaxe para resolver essa ambigüidade é
>   ${$a[1]} para o primeiro caso e ${$a}[1] para o segundo.

De qualquer modo, sua observação pode não estar documentada.

Em se tratando de comportamento inesperado, há um comentário que fala do uso de variável com o nome `this` quando não passado diretamente: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.basics.php#107080

Fontes:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.basics.php
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.variable.php
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: Não esclarece muito a pergunta. Que as chaves são usadas para imprimir as varíaveis, evitando colisão entre o nome a variável e uma string é normal. Mas e quanto a declaração? É recomendado a declaração de variáveis com nomes "exóticos"?

Comment: Ah, e +1 pela informação preciosíssima do `$this`.

Comment: Sempe esqueço a diferente entre colchetes e chaves