# Por que é possível acessar índices de arrays com "{}" chaves?

Tags: php, array, característica-linguagem

Em alguns testes que fiz com PHP, vi que é possível utilizar chaves (`{}`) para acessar índices de `arrays`.

Exemplo:

```
$array = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => ['d' => 4]]

echo $array{'c'}{'d'}; // 4
echo $array{'c'}['d']; // 4
```

Até então, pensava que apenas os colchetes (`[]`) faziam isso.

Sendo assim, quero perguntar:

- Acessar um índice de um `array` com chaves ao invés de colchetes tem algum significado especial?
- Por que é possível usar as duas formas?
- Usar chaves seria considerado fora do padrão? Pergunto isso porque, apesar de funcionar, nunca vi ninguém usando.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-61 Veja a nota um pouco abaixo do exemplo.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77693/qual-%C3%A9-a-utilidade-de-declarar-vari%C3%A1veis-atrav%C3%A9s-de-chavetas (não estou dizendo que é duplicada)

Comment: @DanielOmine pode não ser duplicada, mas é bem parecida mesmo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Acessar um índice de um array com chaves ao invés de colchetes tem algum significado especial?

Não.

> Por que é possível usar as duas formas?

O [manual diz que pode](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing), sem explicações porque ter essa alternativa. Não consigo imaginar uma plausível a não ser gosto. O bfavaretto falou de um teoria sobre ajudar a transição de quem vinha do Perl, um concorrente direto na época. É uma boa teoria, ainda que eu acho um erro fazer esta opção. Não há ganho ter essa alternativa. Tem tanta coisa muito mais radical nas diferenças entre essas linguagens. Mas de fato muita coisa em PHP foi realizado sem muita lógica.

> Usar chaves seria considerado fora do padrão?

Estritamente não.

Já que nunca viu alguém usar, não seja quem vai começar :) gera confusão, já que as chaves costumam ser usadas para outra coisa, o que alias já tem mais de uma finalidade, não adicione mais uma. Deixe as chaves para usar com o que todo mundo está acostumado. A não ser que encontre um motivo bom, o que eu duvido.

Comment: Eu pensei em usar as chaves quando  eu fosse acessar os índices de uma `string`, já que em PHP, ao usar os colchetes, também é possível acessar o índice da string (seria pra diferenciar, mas também acho que seria inventar moda demais).

Comment: Isso, seria só inventar moda.

Comment: Eu li em algum lugar que aceitar `{}` seria uma maneira de atrair gente que mexe com perl.

Comment: @bfavaretto é possível, o que vai atrair gente errada :) Quem gosta de Perl não vai trocar de linguagem, quem acha PHP mais interessante para alguma coisa vai se adaptar.