# O que será impresso na tela por esse script?

Tags: php, script

O que será impresso na tela por esse `script` ?

```
<?php
$foo = 'bar';
$bar = 'foo';
print ${$foo}; 
?>
```

Comment: É PHP isso? script fica beeeem generico.

Comment: Será impresso, **Não sei nem o que estou falando**.

Comment: [Qual é a utilidade de declarar variáveis através de chavetas?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77693/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No PHP um cifrão seguindo de chaves pode ser a definição de uma variável com nomes estranhos ou sua leitura. O que acontece no exemplo é o valor de `$foo` e jogo na leitura então vira `${bar}` que contém o valor `foo`.

[Exemplo - ideone](http://ideone.com/32ijrB)

Relacionado:

[Qual é a utilidade de declarar variáveis através de chavetas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77693/91)

[Caracteres especiais em identificadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38461/91)

Comment: Salvo a minha vida, obrigada :D

Comment: @CarolineWitts, se vc quiser pode criar uma variável dessa forma `${0} = 'wow'; echo ${0}; `

Answer (score -1):

Pela lógica, o valor impresso é bar, mas porque esse valor foi atribuido a variável $foo.

Edit: Sim, testando no Fiddle, é impresso foo, mas não entendi pq...

Comment: Não não, vai imprimir `foo`.

Comment: ai gente, estou perdida agora

Comment: É php por isso o resultado não é bar. hahaha :D

Comment: @renan existem Fiddle's para várias linguagens, inclusive PHP